# sql simultaneous update

Tags: sql

I'm trying to add a like and dislike button to my application and the backend runs on SQL, I've done my research and i read somewhere that it will handle updates in the same table and different rows, but i count the number of likes after the "SELECT " query and then i update the value so what happens if someone likes it at the same time and the value is +1 when it's going to update it? will it update it to +2 or will it stay the same?
thanks

Comment: Look into the concept of ACID: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do this in a single query:

```
    UPDATE items SET likes = likes + 1 WHERE item_id = :id;
```

That statement, assuming you're using a DB that supports transactions, will run as a transaction, and so in isolation.

If you SELECT, modify, and then UPDATE in separate queries, then you run into the concurrent-update problem you described, where one user's changes can overwrite another's with an unfortunate interleaving.

You *could* do it using locks to ensure no bad interleaving, but that will increase complexity, and open up potential for concurrency bugs.